# Creating a dynamic FROM string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I'd like to create a `SELECT` statement where the FROM clause is dynamic, as my database `automatically creates tables` for each passing month (ex. `TABLENAME_201705, TABLENAME_201704,` so on). I'd like to create a query which selects the table of the previous month. Any tips on where I should start?

Comment: How big are these tables?  It might make better sense to keep just one table with a date column which could be used to identify a particular month/year.

Comment: as @TimBiegeleisen suggested, having 12 tables added each year is not a great design IMO

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen There are over millions of data points per table.

Comment: @Hatik we only keep 3 the past three months as the current table is updated daily with live data

Comment: then I can suggest to create a package and use `sql_stmt := 'select * from ' || 'table_name_' || your_date;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO smth;` where`sql_stmt` should have the SQL statement that you need, and smth will be the OUT variable in your procedure. However for this you will need a bit of PL/SQL knowledge, this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) might be helpful

Comment: @Hatik Cool. I'll see to learning some PL/SQL. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Mannitude_ you are welcome, PL/SQL is indeed quite useful thing for oracle based apps